# unity grammar recognizer not working

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, grammar

I'm trying to use the windows 10 grammar recognizer from unity but it's not detecting anything.

```
private GrammarRecognizer grammarRecognizer;
```

on the start function I have:

```
grammarRecognizer = new GrammarRecognizer(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/SRGS/myGrammar.xml", ConfidenceLevel.Low);
grammarRecognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += grammarRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
grammarRecognizer.Start();
```

I also have this function:

```
void grammarRecognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
{
    System.Action keywordAction;
    Debug.Log("word said: " + args.text + " - conf: " + args.confidence);
    if (args.confidence >= ConfidenceLevel.Medium) 
        Debug.Log("Confidence is low");
    print(args.semanticMeanings);
}
```

but the previous function is never being called because it's never recognizing anything. I have this grammar:

```xml
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="en-US" root="playCommands"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar">

  <rule id="playCommands">
    <ruleref uri="#playAction" />
    <item> the </item>
    <ruleref uri="#fileWords" />
  </rule>

  <rule id="playAction">
    <one-of>
      <item> play </item>
      <item> start </item>
      <item> begin </item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>

  <rule id="fileWords">
    <one-of>
      <item> song </item>
      <item> tune </item>
      <item> track </item>
      <item> item </item>
    </one-of>
  </rule>
</grammar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try taking out the spaces around the words in the  tags. That fixed it for me.